# PyQT5 QTreeWidget get full path of clicked element

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtreewidget

I hope you all safe and healthy. My problem is simply I am trying to make a video player and I have QTreeWidget with elements (folders & files) from given path on it. I want to make play video when double clicked on element in QTreeWidget.

```
# How I create tree, fill and detect double click.
self.tree = QTreeWidget()
self.load_project_structure("resources/videos", self.tree)
self.tree.itemDoubleClicked.connect(self.handler)

def load_project_structure(self, startpath, tree):
    for element in os.listdir(startpath):
        path_info = startpath + "/" + element
        parent_itm = QTreeWidgetItem(tree, [os.path.basename(element)])
        if os.path.isdir(path_info):
            self.load_project_structure(path_info, parent_itm)
            parent_itm.setIcon(0, QIcon('img/folder.png'))
        else:
            parent_itm.setIcon(0, QIcon('img/file.png'))

def handler(item, column_no):
    print(item, column_no)
```

My Tree is simply like that:

- Folder_1

  - Folder_1.1

    - File_1.1.1.mp4
    - File_1.1.2.mp4
  - Folder 1.2

When I double click to File_1.1.2 I want to get something like that (and thats how I can play video):

> Folder_1/Folder_1.1/File_1.1.2.mp4

but I got this:

> <**main**.Window object at 0x00000275AC0FD558> PyQt5.QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem object at 0x00000275AC0FD828>

Any help is welcome. Thank you in advance

Comment: You "got this" from doing what, exactly?

Comment: Sorry for not mention. it was printed output from handler function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have to do is iterate over the parents of the items and concatenate them:

```py
def handler(self, item, column_no):
    texts = []
    while item is not None:
        texts.append(item.text(0))
        item = item.parent()
    path = "/".join(texts)
    print(path)
```

Another simpler method is to use a role to store the full path

```
def load_project_structure(self, startpath, tree):
    for element in os.listdir(startpath):
        path_info = os.path.join(startpath, element)
        parent_itm = QTreeWidgetItem(tree, [os.path.basename(element)])
        parent_itm.setData(0, Qt.UserRole, path_info)
        if os.path.isdir(path_info):
            self.load_project_structure(path_info, parent_itm)
            parent_itm.setIcon(0, QIcon('img/folder.png'))
        else:
            parent_itm.setIcon(0, QIcon('img/file.png'))

def handler(self, item, column_no):
    print(item.data(0, Qt.UserRole))
```